# extend Twig to define assets url

Tags: php, symfony, twig, silex

I read the `Silex Cookbook` for Managing Assets in Templates
http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/cookbook/assets.html

and write this code in my `app/app.php` :

```
$app['twig'] = $app->share($app->extend('twig', function ($twig, $app) {
    $twig->addFunction(new \Twig_SimpleFunction('asset', function ($asset) {
        // implement whatever logic you need to determine the asset path
        return sprintf('http://assets.examples.com/%s', ltrim($asset, '/'));
    }));

    return $twig;
}));

$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    return $app['twig']->render('index.twig', array(
        'title' => "Hello World",
        'colors' => array("red", "green", "yellow"),
    ));
});
```

and  `index.twig` contain :

```
{% extends "layout.twig" %}

{% block title %}
    {{ title }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi quibusdam numquam laudantium eum asperiores non libero odio quae debitis beatae perferendis eius esse molestiae voluptatum vel inventore quasi. Quo sint sequi sunt amet sapiente tempora autem iusto praesentium rerum ducimus.</p>

    <ul>
        {% for color in colors %}
            <li>{{ color }}</li>        
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    {{ asset('/css/styles.css') }}

{% endblock %}
```

Everything is ok, but when I use `asset` in another `twig` files I will get this error:

```
Twig_Error_Syntax in Parser.php line 370:
A template that extends another one cannot have a body in "admin/dashboard.twig" at line 3.
```

for example, my `AdminDashboard` controller contain:

```
<?php


namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use Silex\Application;

class AdminDashboard
{

    function __construct()
    {
        return "Dashboard";

    }

    function indexAction(Application $app)
    {
        return $app['twig']->render('admin/dashboard.twig', array(
            'title' => "Hello World",
            'colors' => array("red", "green", "yellow"),
        ));
    }


}
```

and `admin/dashboard.twig` contain:

```
{% extends "layout.twig" %}

{{ asset('/css/styles.css') }}
```

But when I visit my `admin` page I get above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just read the error message, it's not about the function call:

> A template that extends another one cannot have a body

Your `admin/dashboard.twig` file has `{% extends ... %}` at the first line, which means it extends another template. As you see in the error message, a template that extends another template cannot have body. It can only fill in the blocks defined by the parent template.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, unfortunately I'm is newbie in silex and I think this error may be return to twig extend, sorry